# Penrose tilings and prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, tiling

Can one exclude the idea of prime numbers being a projection (using a proper acceptance domain) of a higher dimensional lattice onto 1D similar to the generation of Penrose tilings (see e.g. [thesis](https://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/mathematics/research/leverhulme-project/documents/bragg-project-dissertation))? Unfortunately I don't find papers on this topic so maybe there are simple arguments I don't come up with.

Comment: You won't find a precise answer there, but you could take a look at: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/06/quasicrystals_and_the_riemann.html and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133581/quasicrystals-and-the-riemann-hypothesis

Comment: My understanding is that growth-rate arguments exclude most of the natural ways of doing this; it's essentially impossible to get any sort of growth rate that isn't $\Theta(n^\alpha)$ via direct projection, and I don't know of any sensible ways of getting the logarithmic term.